# Enable to reproduce the loss of training while predicting

Tags: loss-function

i use CNN model for a regression problem with a custom loss

```
def loss_M2(y_true,y_pred):
    y_true_f=K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f=K.flatten(y_pred)
    M2=K.max(K.abs(K.cumsum((y_pred_f-y_true_f),axis=0)))        
    return M2
```

[image]
ISSUE : when i call `y_train_predict = model.predict(X_train, verbose=0)` and evalaute the loss i get "926" instead of something close to 200 that we see on the image above , here is the numpy function that compute the same custom loss

```
def score_M2(reel,pred):
    return max(abs(np.cumsum(reel-pred)))
```

PS : i checked that the loss_M2 and score_M2 give the same results for the same inputs. 
Please tell me what is happening here.

Comment: I noticed thatt in score_M2 you are substracting __reel-pred__ while in loss_M2 __pred - true__

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately the same issue persists :(

Comment: Are you computing the loss over the same axis?

Comment: Can you give more details about the shapes of data during training and during evaluating?

Comment: my train set has (1000,36,1) as shape. and val set (251,36,1)

Comment: y_train (1000,) and y_val(251,)

Comment: so... it is not the same to compute the cumalative sum over 1000 samples than 251, isn it? just wondering

Comment: Yes but i run 'predict' one the same X_train so i should get the same loss ...!!

Comment: I'd pay attention to the things that are not the same in both computations... for instance, in score_M2 you are not flattening the arrays

Comment: i removed the flattening but keep getting the same results... I don't know what's matter

Comment: You can print here the arrays for the first 10 values and both results for these values

Comment: Which array you would like me to print please ?

Comment: the true and predicted values and the computed losses. I can run it and check what's going on

Comment: Are you performing some data normalization during training? If so, you have to normalize it for predicting

Comment: y_pred
[ 93.361     10.397      5.515    206.093     24.379     44.883
  26.64       4.708      6.525      4.112704]
y_true
[74.32183, 49.488754, 39.4487, 218.02928, 25.579964, 22.995552, 17.774035, 1.858181, 3.0018008, 4.594691]

Comment: Don't they be of size 36?

Comment: y_pred and y_true are my target variable

Answer (score 0):

```
y_pred
[ 93.361     10.397      5.515    206.093     24.379     44.883
  26.64       4.708      6.525      4.112704]
y_true
[74.32183, 49.488754, 39.4487, 218.02928, 25.579964, 22.995552, 17.774035, 1.858181, 3.0018008, 4.594691]
```

[image]

Yes my data are normalized i made sure that what i give to my predict function is the same

Comment: I assume you are also normalizing the data when predicting. Also, if you are using dropout, it has to be disabled in the predicting stage... I encourage to give more info about the network, the procedure you follow and so son... let's see if other users can figure out what's going out.